# What happened to the vim-perl package?

Tags: vim

Ubuntu used to provide a vim-perl package, what ever happened to it? How do I get `:perldo` back?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In 8.04, `vim-perl` became a transitional package for `vim-gtk` which has all the languages. [Find more information here.](http://www.ubuntuupdates.org/package/core/hardy/universe/updates/vim-perl)